# Inexplicable lag in class for audio sampling with PyAudio

Tags: python, performance, time, portaudio, pyaudio

Using the classes I've written below, I am running afoul of apparently impossible timing issues. When `AudioStream.sample()` is called in a loop, the first sample takes about ~12-14ms. Each subsequent call takes about 280ms. I cannot figure out why. What's more, I've timed each individual step in the flow and, cumulatively, they add up to ~12-14ms. The remaining 265ms I can't account for. I've run this on two machines—a MacBook and a brand new iMac (3.2ghz, 16GB RAM), with nearly identical timing results (I'm just using `time.time()`, btw).

I've tried:

- lowering the sample rate
- varying chunk sizes
- using the [platform specific](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#id9) settings for streaming
- using input only
- using a single channel

None of these have more than a minor (ie. microseconds, a millesecond or two at best) impact. I am just stumped.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
from array import array

class AudioSample(object):
    def __init__(self, raw_sample):
        super(AudioSample, self).__init__()
        self.array = array('h', raw_sample)            # ~7.8^-6s
        self.peak = max(self.array)                    # ~4.3^-5s
        self.trough = min(self.array)                  # ~4.2^-5s
        self.mean = sum(self.array) / len(self.array)  # ~1.6^-5s


class AudioStream(object):
    p = None
    stream = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(AudioStream, self).__init__()
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    def sample(self):                                  # ~0.28s after the first time
        try:
            chunk = self.stream.read(1024)             # ~0.01s
            return AudioSample(chunk, 100)             # ~0.001s
        except IOError:  # in case of buffer overflow
            self.init_stream()                         # ~0.004s
            return self.sample()

    def init_stream(self):
        try:
            self.stream.stop_stream()
            self.stream.close()
            self.p.terminate()
        except (AttributeError, IOError) as e:
            pass  # on first pass, no stream exists; on subsequent passes, extant stream should be stopped & overwritten

        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=2, rate=44100, input=True, output=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly problem, in the end; the "lag" was caused by quietly handling the IOError by re-calling the `sample()` method; it turns out, that this exception (thrown due to a buffer-overflow) was being raised upwards of a dozen times depending on the other activity during the loop.

Managing the chunk size & sampling rate was one strategy (but this requires context-sensitive testing). My solution, in the end, is different; if losing frames off the buffer is not an issue for the context, PyAudio's second argument of `stream.read()` method is a boolean which turns off throwing exceptions for buffer overflows, so, this is the resulting solution:

`chunk = self.stream.read(1024, False)`